# В каждом ряду найдите "лишнее" (с точки произношения) слово и объясните почему?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

В каждом ряду найдите "лишнее" (с точки произношения) слово и объясните почему :
1)жесткий, опека, принесенный, осетр
2)консервы, термос, тент, свитер
3)горчичник, коричневый, прачечная, нарочно.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: oleedd Если ответ решил проблему, значит его не успели закрыть. Такие вопросы надо отмечать палочкой.

Comment: @shampar Если д/з неординарное и интересное, то оно достойно того, чтобы ответить, и это будет полезно другим. Какая ещё палочка?

Comment: Рифма с галочкой, а в жизни — указка или линейка. Чтобы отбить желание подсказывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) опека — в других словах произносится Ё.
2) консервы — в других словах произносится Э вместо Е.
Наблюдательный ответ: сви́тер — в других словах ударение на букву Е.
3) коричневый — в слове звук Ш вместо Ч почти не используется.
Продвинутый ответ: нарочно — в других словах обычно произносят Ч (Ш - старомосковский вариант), а здесь исключительно Ш вместо Ч.

Comment: Во втором примере   ответ- тент, т-твёрдое, в других мягкие согласные, ( е произносится как [ э ] )

Comment: Да нет - в термосе тоже все твёрдые: https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/54139-kak-pravilno-[te]rmos-ili-[te]rmos/

Comment: И в "свитере" тоже твёрдая. Слава всё правильно написал, плюсанул ему.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой В "свитере" В мягкая. Возможно, что сутью является "объясните почему", на этом основании можно найти несколько правильных ответов.

Comment: О " В" речь не идёт, это не проблема, вопрос всегда проблемный, здесь проблема в произношении согласных перед  Е в заимствованных словах

Comment: Ну вы же написали "в других мягкие согласные" (разные), а не согласная. Надо точнее выражаться.

Comment: @Людмила: кстати, что интересно: если записать английское произношение слова "свитер" русскими буквами, получится что-то вроде /суэтə/. То есть по-звучанию правильнее по-русски было бы записать через обе Е, когда его заимствовали. Но теперь, ясен пень, как сложилось, так сложилось.

Comment: Но буквосочетание "ea" читается И. Но они произносят Е как исключение.

Comment: По-разному читается. Вот навскидку, где /e/: instead, thread, threat(en), dead, death, wealth, head, spread... Да полно их!

Answer (score 3):

1) жесткий, **оп[э]ка**, принесенный, осетр

*Согласна со Славой*: 2) **консервы**-мягкий согл., термос - твёрдый, тент - твёрдый, свитер - полумягкий - норма эфира, твёрдый - общенародная.

3) горчи[шн]ик, **кори[чн]евый**, праче[шн]ая, *наро[**шн**]о.*

*Общими усилиями ответили*: **опека, консервы, коричневый**.

Comment: термос [тэ],  свитер [тэ], тент [тэ]... **конс['э]рвы**

Comment: Кори[шн]евый - http://gramota.ru/forum/veche/65799/

Comment: Это школьное задание по современному произношению, а не по старомосковскому, в современных словарях кори[чн]евый

Comment: Часто можно услышать и "горчиЧник", и "прачеЧная".

Comment: С Грамоты: *В некоторых словах возможны варианты: булочная – було[чн]ая и було[шн]ая, прачечная – праче[чн]ая и праче[шн]ая.*

Comment: Со Славой согласна, скорее всего, ответ консервы, термос - твёрдый согласный, а вот свитер - в словаре "Русская речь в эфире" - полумягкий. С вариантами тоже согласна, но ответ всё же коричневый - там  в современных словарях без вариантов. Варианты узаконили совсем недавно.

Comment: Насчёт коричневого согласен. Только Вы бы лучше Ё написали в первом пункте. И в "опеке" не Э.

Comment: Общими усилиями ответили: опека, консервы, коричневый.

Comment: Артём, согласна с Вами, но ведь это в учебниках так, в задании, может, и специально, чтобы не подсказывать.

Comment: А [э] - звук, е- два звука, это же йотированная буква

Comment: В задании-то конечно, я имел в виду, что в ответе Вы же всё уже разжевываете, и там-то и хорошо поставить Ё. Насчёт Э: просто у "опеки" и "тента" у Вас одинаково Э стоят, но при этом одна твёрдая, а другая мягкая.